# How to alter order of list items in a form?

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

I have made a Spring MVC app that displays a list of items to a user - how could I change the order of those items in JSP, so that the new order gets submitted to the server?

For example, the user gets the following list:

1. Pet Cat
2. Pet Dog
3. Pet Bird

The list is made up with this form:

```
<form:form action="/modifypetlist.do" method="POST" modelAttribute="petList">
  <fieldset>
    <div>
      <ul id="sortable">
        <c:forEach items="${petList.list}" varStatus="vs">
          <li class="ui-state-default">
           <form:label path="list[${vs.index}].pet">Pet</form:label>
           <form:input path="list[${vs.index}].pet" />
          </li>
       </c:forEach>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <input type="submit" value="send">
   </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

I have included some Javascript that enables the user to drag and drop the rows in the list, e.g. moving the Dog line above the Cat line.

How do I communicate this to the server? (how could I rebuild the petList model from the form fields?) I can currently read the list in the server after submitting the form, but the list items come in original order, even if I change the names in the form (eg. Cat --> Mouse)

Answer (score 1):

That's because they're naturally ordered by their primary key (which is an index), so usually the id of the row.

Try adding a "rank" field in the table that you will update once the data has been sorted and order your results by rank.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, but is there a way of altering the "rank" from javascript (when the list item is dragged) ? Or do I have to settle for an old-school numeric field in the form?

Comment: Of course there is a way to move things around in javascript but how the hell are you then supposed to retain the order ? You might wanna try swapping the ids of the items in the list in the database bu that really doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to persist the order information in your persistance layer. By doing this, you will need to trigger a call (an javascript ajax call for exemple) everytime you modify the order. This call should sent a request to the application server who will call the proper service to update your persistance layer for that list.

Then, you will also need to adapt your persistance layer to order the list with the "rank" information you persisted earlier when comes to moment to display your page.

I guess this is the most efficient way.

Good luck !

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. I think my problem roots to my desire to modify the list at once (add, delete items and change their order -> then save the new list at one go). It seems there's really no other sensible way than handle each change separately.

Comment: Here's what you can do. On every event that happens on your list, you trigger a call to your application server. That call will contain your entire list state and your persistance layer will just overwrite everything everytime. That way, one single operation on your list will handle every possibility.